# Add hanging indents in list of figure entries in Latex

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, thesis

I am writing my Thesis. However the i am facing a problem while formatting list of Figure. I wanted to know how could I add hanging indents to the Figure Captions So that it is alligned to the first Line. I am using Thesis Class, which by default does not write the Word "Figure" and "Table" before Figure Number

[image: Initial Output without tocloft]

Thus I have used `tocloft` package to Add words Figure and Table before figure and table Number. Doing this shifts the first line but the 2nd line stays where it was.

[image: Using tocloft package].

Is there any way in which i can align the 1st and second line keeping the word "Figure" intact. I have provided a fraction of code I am using. However, I have included all packages I have used.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, openright]{Thesis} % Paper size, default font size and one-sided paper
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[square, numbers]{natbib}


\hypersetup{urlcolor=black, colorlinks=true} % Colors hyperlinks in blue - change to black if annoyingv`    
\title{\ttitle} % Defines the thesis title 
\setlength{\parindent}{20pt}


\setlength\cftbeforefigskip{8pt}    % To add line spacing between entries in LOF
\setlength\cftbeforechapskip{8pt}   % To add line spacing between entries in LOC
\setlength\cftbeforetabskip{8pt}    % To add line spacing between entries in LOT

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\NAT@nmfmt}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\makeatother

\frontmatter 

\fancyhead{} % Clears all page headers and footers
\rhead{\thepage} % Sets the right side header to show the page number
\lhead{} % Clears the left side page header

\pagestyle{fancy} % Finally, use the "fancy" page style to implement the FancyHdr headers

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % New command to make the lines in the title page

% PDF meta-data
\hypersetup{pdftitle={\ttitle}}
\hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}


\pagestyle{plain}

\acknowledgements{Some Random texts}
\newpage
\addtotoc{Abstract} % Add the "Abstract" page entry to the Contents
\abstract{Some random Texts for Abstract}
\newpage 

\pagestyle{fancy} % The page style headers have been "empty" all this time, now use the "fancy" headers as defined before to bring them back
\addtotoc{Contents}
\lhead{\emph{Contents}} % Set the left side page header to "Contents"
\tableofcontents % Write out the Table of Contents
\newpage
\addtotoc{List of Figures}
\lhead{\emph{List of Figures}} % Set the left side page header to "List of Figures"

%Fragment of code for Writing "Figure" in front of Figure number
{
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
  \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoffigures % Write out the List of Figures
}
\newpage

\addtotoc{List of Tables}
\lhead{\emph{List of Tables}} % Set the left side page header to "List of Tables"
%Fragment of code for Writing "Figure" in front of Figure number
{
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
  \renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoftables % Write out the List of Tables
}

\mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering

\pagestyle{fancy} % Return the page headers back to the "fancy" style

% Include the chapters of the thesis as separate files from the Chapters folder
% Uncomment the lines as you write the chapters

\input{Chapters/Chapter1}
\input{Chapters/Chapter2}
\input{Chapters/Chapter3}
\input{Chapters/Chapter4}
\input{Chapters/Chapter5}

\clearpage % Start a new page
\appendix % Cue to tell LaTeX that the following 'chapters' are Appendices

% Include the appendices of the thesis as separate files from the Appendices folder
% Uncomment the lines as you write the Appendices

\input{Appendices/AppendixA}

\backmatter

\label{References}

\lhead{\emph{References}} % Change the page header to say "Bibliography"
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} % Use the "custom" BibTeX style for formatting the Bibliography

\bibliography{references} % The references (bibliography) information are stored in the file named "Bibliography.bib"

\newpage
\include{LOP}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Where I am doing the mistake???

Comment: Unfortunately your example is neither minimal nor complete and therefore not a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964). But because you are already using [package `tocloft`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft), I would suggest to read section 2.3 of the user manual. Hint: If you don't know, how to replace the `X` in `\cftXindent` or `\cftXnumwidth` (see the manual) try `fig` for the figure entries or `tab` for the tables, as listed on page 9 of the manual.

Comment: I tried setting `cftfignumwidth`. In a caption written in two lines... increasing or decreasing  `cftfignumwidth'  changes the indentation of both 1st and 2nd line by same amount... i want to push only the 2nd line by some amount keeping the 1st line untouched

Answer (score 0):

The way you redefine `\numberline`:

```
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}
```

Make `cftfignumwidth` doesn't account the width of word `\figurename~`. Because it is outside the command `\numberline`. You shouldn't redefine `\numberline` like that. Instead, package `tocloft` provide the commands `\cftfigpresnum` and `\cftfigaftersnum` to put extra contents before and after the number.

Here is an example how to use these commands to achieve what you want:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength\cftbeforefigskip{8pt}
\settowidth{\cftfignumwidth}{Figure~1.100~}% set the \cftfignumwidth to certain length of text in case you have a huge numbered figure, e.g., Figure~1.100~
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure~}% add the word figure and a space before the number
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{~} % add a space after the number

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{One}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long Caption}
\end{figure}
\setcounter{figure}{10}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long Caption}
\end{figure}
\setcounter{figure}{100}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{A very very very very very very very very very very very very long Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]